# Why can't I access my file despite it being in the ressources?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, file

I am trying to open a JSON file in swift CLI in order to parse it.
However, when I can't seem to generate a proper file URL despite the file being in the resources.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "json") {
    do {
        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        print(fileUrl)
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl, options: .mappedIfSafe)
        print(data)
        let cities: [City] = try decoder.decode([City].self, from: data);
        return cities;
    } catch {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

If i open the "Build Phases" menu, I can see the test.json file inside, but swift can't access the file when I build.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        readData()
    }

    // MARK: - More
    func readData() {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "json") {
            if let jsonData = readFileContent(path: path) {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([City].self, from: jsonData)
                    print(result)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("\(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func readFileContent(path: String) -> Data? {
        do {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            return data
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the issue with my execution however is that it can't seem to find the file "test.json" at all : it doesn't go into the ‘if let path = ...‘ block.

Comment: It's been tested.  Don't blame me.  If it doesn't work, there must be something that you have not mentioned.